# Supported .NET RabbitMQ.Client.dll For .NET 4.0 Framework

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, compatibility, rabbitmq.client

We have multiple client applications with a lot of data transfer among them. We got the idea of putting messages into a queue instead of storing everything in DB and reading from it. So we are building a library (.NET DLL) with RabbitMQ message broker so that client applications can use the DLL and send message.

Here is the challenge that I am having, some of our client host/producer application machines have very old machines like Windows XP, 7 (having .NET 4.0) and some others are Windows servers 2016, 2019, windows 10, 11 (having .NET >= 4.5). As per my research, we need to use different RabbitMQ.Client.dll for .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 Frameworks. Is there any other way that we can use one .NET C# RabbitMQ.Client.dll for all the environments?

I would really appreciate and encourage any ideas/approaches/solutions for the above challenge

Comment: You'll likely need to [multi-target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/multiple-target-frameworks-project-file) and use different versions for the different target frameworks. You're unlikely to find a current supported versions for RabbitMQ that supports all of those versions, given that things like .NET 4 are [out-of-support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework).

Comment: Hi @MartinCostello, Thank you. But which version of RabbitMQ.Client.dll should I use? Either RabbitMQ.Client.dll 5.x or RabbitMQ.Client.dll 3.x? According to RabbitMQ documentation, .NET 4.0 supports 3.x and .NET 4.5 supports 5.x

Comment: I don't know - that depends on what features you need to use in your application, what's available in the various versions of the RabbitMQ packages, and what versions there are. You'll need to look at the supported targets in NuGet.org and the release notes for the library to see what there differences in functionality are.